# Android Firebase handling FCM notification clicks using custom data

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I was using the following code and all was well until i migrated to androidx. Now it is sending messages but not handling the clicks. Here is the code in my manifest file

```
<service android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
        android:value="@string/default_notification_channel_id" />
```

Then MyFirebaseMessagingService

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {


private static final String TAG = "FCM Service";
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);

        RemoteMessage.Notification notification = remoteMessage.getNotification();
        Map<String, String> data = remoteMessage.getData();

        sendNotification(notification, data);
    }
/**
 * Create and show a custom notification containing the received FCM message.
 *
 * @param notification FCM notification payload received.
 * @param data FCM data payload received.
 */
private void sendNotification(RemoteMessage.Notification notification, Map<String, String> data) {
    Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher);

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "channel_id")
            .setContentTitle(notification.getTitle())
            .setContentText(notification.getBody())
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setContentInfo(notification.getTitle())
            .setLargeIcon(icon)
            .setColor(Color.RED)
            .setLights(Color.RED, 1000, 300)
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);

    try {
        String picture_url = data.get("picture_url");
        if (picture_url != null && !"".equals(picture_url)) {
            URL url = new URL(picture_url);
            Bitmap bigPicture = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
            notificationBuilder.setStyle(
                    new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle().bigPicture(bigPicture).setSummaryText(notification.getBody())
            );
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    // Notification Channel is required for Android O and above
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(
                "channel_id", "channel_name", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
        );
        channel.setDescription("channel description");
        channel.setShowBadge(true);
        channel.canShowBadge();
        channel.enableLights(true);
        channel.setLightColor(Color.RED);
        channel.enableVibration(true);
        channel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{100, 200, 300, 400, 500});
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }

    notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
}
```

}

Lastly this was the code i was using the get custom data and handling it after notification click in my main activity onCreate nethod

```
//FCM
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null && extras.containsKey("rateUpdate")) {
        try {
            startActivity(new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW", Uri.parse("market://details?id=tino.varconn.com.fastnetworks")));
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException unused) {
            startActivity(new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW", Uri.parse("http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.myapp")));
        }
    }
```

In the firebase console under custom data i would write the key as anything but the custom data as "rateUpdate".
Can someone tell me why it is no longer working?